# Firebase max writes in a cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to stuff my Cloud Firestore database with data using batch writes and wondering how many writes can a Cloud Function tolerate before it got removed by timeout?

So far I was able to push **20K** rows. Does any one know what is the limit if any?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no set limit for writes.  All the writes will complete if there is time for them to complete.  Cloud Functions just imposes a limit of time.  Cloud Functions time out after 60 seconds by default.  That can be [configured](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) up to 540 seconds.